# Remove duplicate rows between two different columns

Tags: sql, sybase

I'm having an issue removing duplicates between two different columns. Here's my current select query:

```
SELECT e.id AS EventId, 
    rt.player_nbr AS PlayerId, 
    rt.partner_nbr AS PartnerId
FROM eventTable e
    INNER JOIN resultsTable rt ON e.id = rt.id
```

Here are the results:

```
EventId | PlayerId | PartnerId
 1049   |  20652   |  80458
 1049   |  20702   |  310816
 1049   |  80394   |  190666
 1049   |  80394   |   null
 1049   |  80458   |  20652
 1049   | 190666   |  80394
```

From the results, you can see there are duplicates where the PlayerId and PartnerId are just flopped. I'd like to remove the duplicate rows to where it would look like this:

```
EventId | PlayerId | PartnerId
 1049   |  20652   |  80458
 1049   |  20702   |  310816
 1049   |  80394   |  190666
 1049   |  80394   |   null
```

I have tried this and a few other things so far without success:

```
SELECT e.id AS EventId, 
    rt.player_nbr AS PlayerId, 
    rt.partner_nbr AS PartnerId
FROM eventTable e
    INNER JOIN resultsTable rt ON e.id = rt.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM eventTable e2
        INNER JOIN resultsTable rt2 ON e2.id = rt2.id
    WHERE rt2.player_nbr = rt.partner_nbr
        AND rt2.partner_nbr = rt.player_nbr
)
```

Any suggestions as to how I could best handle this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample query uses `not exists`, so let's continue down that path.  The logic is that you want all rows were `player_nbr < partner_nbr`.  Then you want rows where `player_nbr > partner_nbr` is true but that there is other row with `player_nbr < partner_nbr`.  The following is the logic in SQL:

```
SELECT e.id AS EventId, 
       rt.player_nbr AS PlayerId, 
       rt.partner_nbr AS PartnerId
FROM eventTable e INNER JOIN
     resultsTable rt
      ON e.id = rt.id
WHERE rt.player_nbr < rt.partner_nbr OR
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM resultsTable rt2 
                  WHERE rt2.id = rt.id AND
                        rt2.player_nbr = rt.partner_nbr AND
                        rt2.partner_nbr = rt.player_nbr
                  );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked great! I'm just curious as to why the `NOT EXISTS` code is needed at all? It seems like this works without it.

Comment: It looks like the `NOT EXISTS` code is used for in the case when the `partner_nbr` returns `null` and since `null` is considered less than any number `player_nbr` could be, it excludes those results. Another way to do this without `NOT EXISTS` is simply flipping the less than sign to greater than. So the where clause would look like this: `WHERE rt.player_nbr > rt.partner_nbr` This has worked for me, please correct me if I'm wrong. It helps speed the query up a bit.